# mongoDB tool is change?

Tags: mongodb, export-to-excel

I was using mongoDB tool with 3t and nosql. Sometimes I have to export to Excel, is it correct that both tools have been changed so that only paid members can use the export function? Please tell me which tools I can export for free Thank you always.

thank you for always

Comment: How is it relative to domain-driven design?

Comment: Explain more about your problem. Why do you need to export Excel from MongoDB? Is it programmatically? Mongo Compass has tools to export your query.